# Store difference of two columns pandas in previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe structured in this way:

```
#    DateTime       Open       Close   
1    2000-01-04    1420    1460
2    2000-01-05    1470    1480 
3    2000-01-06    1460    1420
4    2000-01-07    1420    1430
```

It is very important, in order to solve my problem, to calculate the difference beetween Close and Open, and convert the result in a binary value -1 if the difference is negative, 1 is the difference is positive.

It is very simple to do this in this way:

```
df['label'] = (df['close'] - df['open'] > 0).astype(int)
df.loc[df['label'] == 0, ['label']] = -1
```

In this way I get the following result:

```
#    DateTime       Open       Close       Label   
1    2000-01-04    1420    1460    1
2    2000-01-05    1470    1480    1 
3    2000-01-06    1460    1420    -1
4    2000-01-07    1420    1430    1
```

However, now I want to put the next row result in the previous one, in order to get this result:

```
#    DateTime       Open       Close       Label   
1    2000-01-04    1420    1460    1
2    2000-01-05    1470    1480    -1 
3    2000-01-06    1460    1420    1
4    2000-01-07    1420    1430    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df['label'] = (df['close'] - df['open'] > 0).astype(int)

# shift by -1 the value of label so for the DateTime x you have the label of x+1
df['label'] = df['label'].shift(-1)

# remove the last one row because it have NaN as label
df = df[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use shift to do so

```
df['Label'] = df['Label'].shift(-1)
```

Comment: Why I have to shift the close value by one row? And open? This doens't solve my problem

Comment: sorry, see my edit - meant to refer to Label instead of Close